# Django-Celery worker hangs when SQL Server Database crashes using FreeTDS driver

Tags: python, sql-server, django, celery, django-celery

I have a celery worker, running on a Ubuntu 14.04 server, that is reading and writing to an MSSQL Server database using pyodbc and the freetds driver. When the SQL Server goes down, the function fails as expected and the celery worker starts trying to clean up and get ready for the next task. At this time, the worker calls django's "connection.close()" method. This method appears to send a command to rollback any incomplete transactions. Since the server is down this throws an exception that is not caught by the celery worker. The worker then hangs and neither releases the task or move on to the next task.

I tried overriding the on_failure and after_return methods for the function and calling connection.close() there (as specified in other answers), but that didn't work. I suspect it is because the when I call connection.close() it has the same issue, and just bubbles the exception up, or because celery's cleanup code gets run before those two methods get called.

Any ideas on how to either catch this exception before it gets to celery, or avoid it all together?

Below is the stack trace of the exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 283, in trace_task
>       state, retval, uuid, args, kwargs, None,
>
> File "/var/www/cortex/corespring/tasks.py", line 13, in after_return
>       connections['xxx'].close()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/**init**.py", line 317, in close
>       self.connection.close()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyodbc.py", line 2642, in close
>       self.rollback()
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyodbc.py", line 2565, in rollback
>       check_success(self, ret)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyodbc.py", line 987, in check_success
>       ctrl_err(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, ODBC_obj.dbc_h, ret, ODBC_obj.ansi)
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyodbc.py", line 965, in ctrl_err
>       raise DatabaseError(state,err_text)
>
> DatabaseError: (u'08S01', u'[08S01] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Write to the server failed')